# Apply the comments (insert ";" as the first char) to the 2nd file

Tags: shell, sed, awk

This must be easy for some of the experts here - I can't figure it out:

```
File1:  
0000001 test1  
;0000002 test2  
;0000003 test3  
0000005 test5  
;00000006 test6  

File2:  
000001 test1  
000002 test2  
000003 test3  
000004 test4  
000005 test5  
000006 test6  
000007 test7
```

The output should be:

```
000001 test1  
;000002 test2  
;000003 test3  
000004 test4  
000005 test5  
;000006 test6  
000007 test7
```

Notes: - Both files are sorted;
       - the output file should have the same number of lines as the File2, with the ";" char copied over from the File1.

Much obliged

Comment: Eh? are file 1 and 2 both input? which bits of the output relate to which files? I could probably do it, but I can't figure out what "it" is!

Comment: Yup, both File1 and File2 are input. I would like to have a 3rd file created based on the rules above:

Comment: Your rules are incomplete.  If the first line of file1 is "; 000001 banana" and the first line of file2 is "000001 apple", what is the desired first line of the output?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks for pointing that out! The text after the numbers is not as important. Guess the rule is to copy the text from File2, regardless of what the text is in File1.

Answer (score 2):

This does the trick:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read f2line
do
    # strip just the test id (chars after the space)
    testId=`echo $f2line | awk '{print $2}'`
    # If file1 has a line for the test starting with a ';'  then prefix the line
    # from file2 with a ';', else just print the line from file2
    grep -q ";[1234567890]\+ $testId" file1
    if [ $? = 0 ] ; then
       echo ";$f2line"
    else
        echo $f2line
    fi
done < file2
```

Comment: This reads all of file1 for every line of file2.  That's pretty expensive.

Comment: Depends on the file size - unless you are getting into millions of lines it wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Untested:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR {if ($0 ~ /^;/) comment[substr($1,2)+0] = 1; next}
  ($1+0) in comment {print ";" $0; next}
  {print}
' file1 file2
```

Using "+0" to convert "0001" to "1" since the first field has different numbers of 0's in the two files.

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired results.

Comment: @glennjackman lol, guess what... My assumption that both files are sorted proved to be wrong ;(  Not sure how to sort both files so I could apply your solution

Comment: @Sacha_NETworks, this solution does not require the files to be sorted. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^;0*\(......\) .*/!d;s||/^\1/s/^/;/|' file1 | sed -f - file2
000001 test1  
;000002 test2  
;000003 test3  
000004 test4  
000005 test5  
;000006 test6  
000007 test7
```

Comment: Spoke too soon... It works great for the test example where both files are sorted. My real files are not sorted... eh...

Comment: It should make no difference if the files are sorted or not, as the keys are matched not the position in file. That is sed commands are generated for records with the keys ending in 2,3 and 6 on the first field in file1 and file2. Or am I missing something?